# IZpack loading/saving values from a .properties file

Tags: java, izpack

I am trying to create an installer using IZpack. I created my own panel test.java and i have to read the default values from config.properties file to display them on UI created by test panel and vice versa(we are allowing the user to change this default value coming from .properties file and it has to be saved in .properties file again once we done with the installation
Can you please share a simple code snippet till java end if any one did that previously?

Thanks,
Sekhar

Answer (score -1):

If you ask google for code snippets  to a properties manager you will find a lot of examples. Here is one for writing and reading in a properties file:

[Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/properties/properties-file-java-example/)

Comment: we are configuring the .properties file in the install.xml as follows. <parsable targetfile="$INSTALL_PATH/custom.properties" type="javaprop" parse="yes" /> .how we make it available to our custom panel class. instead of loading using absolute path??

Comment: This is talking about loading properties files in general not for izpack.